# Word that conveys being absent from an appointment

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word that conveys being absent from an appointment? The closest words I can think of are "ditch" and "dump," but both are rather informal. I want to say something along the lines of:

> I went in the office at 3pm to meet Bob, but Bob ditched/dumped me.

I realize that it's perhaps more common to say, "Bob did not show up," but I want a stronger expression that connotes a willful act of neglect or carelessness.

Comment: I don't know how one can be wilfully careless, but "Bob didn't bother to show up" might successfully indicate disapproval. [The question in the title doesn't match what you appear to be asking, by the way]

Comment: "Stood me up" seems a bit casual. I like "didn't bother to show up" -- Thanks!

Comment: Just because someone did not make a schedule appointment does not mean that they “didn’t bother”. That requires extra knowledge of circumstance and intent — which is precisely why they are normally just called ***no-shows***, since that does not presume to know such things. There are many possible reasons for someone missing an appointment, of which not bothering is merely one out of many.

Comment: By the way, this is the 90000th post recorded on English.SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone who missed an appointment is sometimes called a ***no-show***.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to condemn Bob because you know that he deliberately didn't show up for the scheduled appointment (Maybe he does that often), you could always say:

> **...but he blew me off.**

**He stood me up** is what you'd say when someone makes a social date:

> Stood Up (Ricky Nelson song)
>   (by Willis Dickerson and Erma Herrold)
>   Well, I've been waitin' ever since eight
>   Guess my baby's got another date
>   **Stood up, broken-hearted, again**
>
> I'll bet she's out havin' a ball
>   Not even thinkin' of me at all
>   **Stood up, broken-hearted, again**